# i'm having issues with code syntax e.g. : null is not valid at this position, expecting ')'

Tags: mysql, sql

i am very new to SQL and have to complete my first ever project. i keep getting errors to do with syntax and i have no idea where i've gone wrong, i've checked for commas, hyphens in the wrong place and feel like i'm going mad. can someone help me please?

```
the errors:

1. (49, 'Purple Kiss', null, '퍼플키스', '2021-03-15', 'RBW', 7, 7, 'PLORY', true), "null" is not valid at this position, expecting ')'
```

(again, where is the null coming from?)

```
2. (37, 'Uni.T', null, '유니티', '2018-05-18', 'Unit Culture', 8, 9, false), extraneous input false found, expecting ')'
```

(what is an extraneous input?)

```
3. (26, 'The Ark', null, '디아크', '2015-04-12', 'Music K', 5, 5, null, false),
```

9 is not valid at this position, expecting ')'
(not sure where the 9 is coming from)

```
it might be a really simple fix, but again, this is my first project and have no idea what's wrong, please help! i don't know if it's something to do with the korean characters? i read somewhere to use 'NVARCHAR' as the datatype so that's what i used, please explain it to me like i'm a child xD







create database female_kpop_idols;

use female_kpop_idols;

create table kpop_girlgroups
(idol_id int primary key auto_increment not null, 
eng_name varchar(50) not null, 
short_name varchar(50), 
kor_name nvarchar(50) not null, 
debut date not null, 
company varchar(50) not null, 
members int not null,
orig_members int not null,
fanclub varchar(50), 
active boolean);

insert into kpop_girlgroups
values
(1, 'Baby V.O.X', null, '베이비복스', '1997-07-05', 'DR Music', 5, 5, null, false),
(2, 'S.E.S', null, '에스.이.에스', '1997-11-01', 'SM', 3, 3, null, false),
(3, 'Fin.K.L', null, '핑클', '1998-05-22', 'DSP', 4, 4, null, 
(4, 'Brown Eyed Girls', 'B.E.G', '브라운 아이드 걸스    ', '2006-03-02', 'Mystic', 4, 4, 'Everlasting', true),
(5, 'Wonder Girls', 'WG', '원더걸스', '2007-02-13', 'JYP', 4, 5, 'Wonderful', false),
(6, 'Kara', null, '카라', '2007-03-29', 'DSP', 4, 5, 'Kamilia', false),
(7, 'Girls\' Generation', 'SNSD', '2007-08-05', 'SM', 5, 9, 'SONE', true),
(8, 'After School', null, '애프터스쿨', '2009-01-15', 'Pledis', 6, 5, 'Playgirlz', false),
(9, '2NE1', null, '투애니원', '2009-05-06', 'YG', 3, 4, 'Blackjack', false),
(10, '4Minute', null, '포미닛', '2009-06-15', 'Cube', 5, 5, '4nia', false),
(11, 'T-ara', null, '티아라', '2009-07-29', 'MBK', 4, 6, 'Queen\'s', true), -- hiatus --
(12, 'f(x)', null, '에프엑스', '2009-08-24', 'SM', 4, 5, 'MeU', false),
(13, 'Sistar', null, '씨스타', '2010-03-06', 'Starship', 4, 4, 'STAR1', false),
(14, 'missA', null, '미쓰에이', '2010-07-01', 'JYP', 3, 4, 'Say A', false),
(15, 'Girl\'s Day', 'GsD', '걸스데이', '2010-07-09', 'DreamT', 4, 5, 'Dai5y', true), -- hiatus --
(16, 'Rania', null, '라니아', '2011-04-06', 'DR Music', 5, 8, null, false), -- redebuted as Black Swan --
(17, 'Brave Girls', null, '브레이브걸스', '2011-04-08', 'Brave', 4, 5, null, true), 
(18, 'Apink', null, '에이핑크', '2011-04-19', 'Plan A', 6, 7, 'Pink Panda', true),
(19, 'EXID', null, '이엑스아이디', '2012-02-16', 'Yedang', 5, 6, 'LEGO', true),
(20, 'AOA', null, '에이오에이', '2012-07-30', 'FNC', 4, 8, 'ELVIS', true), -- hiatus --
(21, 'Mamamoo', null, '마마무', '2014-06-18', 'RBW', 4, 4, 'Moomoo', true),
(22, 'Red Velevet', 'RV', '레드벨벳', '2014-08-01', 'SM', 5, 4, true),
(23, 'Minx', null, '밍스', '2014-09-18', 'Happy Face', 5, 5, false), -- redebuted as DreamCatcher --
(24, 'Gfriend', null, '여자친구', '2015-01-15', 'Source', 6, 6, 'Buddy', false),
(25, 'CLC', null, '씨엘씨', '2015-03-19', 'Cube', 7, 5, 'Cheshire', false),
(26, 'The Ark', null, '디아크', '2015-04-12', 'Music K', 5, 5, null, false), -- some members redebuted as KHAN --
(27, 'Oh My Girl', 'OHMG', '오마이걸', '2015-04-21', 'WM', 6, 8, 'Miracle', true),
(28, 'TWICE', null, '트와이스', '2015-10-20', 'JYP', '9, '9, 'ONCE', true),
(29, 'WJSN', 'Cosmic Girls', '2016-02-25', 'Starship', 13, 12, 'Ujung', true),
(30, 'IOI', 'I.O.I', '아이오아이', '2016-05-04', 'YMC', 11, 11, null, false),
(31, 'BLACKPINK', null, '블랙핑크', '2016-08-08', 'YG', 4, 4, 'BLINK', true),
(32, 'Momoland', null, '모모랜드', '2016-11-09', 'Duble Kick', 9, 6, true),
(33, 'DreamCatcher', null, '드림캐쳐', '2017-01-13', 'Happy Face', 7, 7, 'InSomnia', true),
(34, 'Pristin', null, '프리스틴', '2017-03-21', 'Pledis', 10, 10, 'HIgh', false), -- some redebuted as Hinapia -- 
(35, 'fromis_9', null, '프로미스나인', '2018-01-24', 'Pledis', 9, 9, 'Flover', true),
(36, '(G)I-DLE', null, '(여자)아이들', '2018-05-02', 'Cube', 5, 6, 'Neverland', true),
(37, 'Uni.T', null, '유니티', '2018-05-18', 'Unit Culture', 8, 9, false), -- come back to this one and add Sonamoo, SPICA, DIA, April, Dal Shabet, Laboum, The ARK --
(38, 'KHAN', null, '칸', '2018-05-23', 'Maroo', 2, 2, false),
(39, 'Loona', 'LOOΠΔ', '이달의 소녀', '2018-08-20', 'Blockberry', 12, 12, 'Orbit', true),
(40, 'IZ*ONE', 'IZONE', '아이즈원', '2018-10-29', 'Off The Record', 12, 12, 'WIZ*ONE' false),
(41, 'Cherry Bullet', null, '체리블렛', '2019-01-21', 'FNC', 7, 10, 'Lullet', true),
(42, 'ITZY', null, '있지', '2019-02-12', 'JYP', 5, 5, 'MIDZY', true),
(43, 'Everglow', null, '에버글로우   ', '2019-03-18', 'Yuehua', 6, 6, 'Forever', true),
(44, 'Rocket Punch', null, '로켓펀치', '2019-08-07', 'Woollim', 6, 6, 'Ketchy', true),
(45, 'Hinapia', null, '희나피아', '2019-11-03', 'Alseubit', 5, 5, 'UBY', false);
```

Comment: Incorrect rows: `(28, 'TWICE', null, '트와이스', '2015-10-20', 'JYP', '9, '9, 'ONCE', true),` - problem with quote chars; `(40, 'IZ*ONE', 'IZONE', '아이즈원', '2018-10-29', 'Off The Record', 12, 12, 'WIZ*ONE' false),` - lost comma; `(3, 'Fin.K.L', null, '핑클', '1998-05-22', 'DSP', 4, 4, null,` - lost data part.

Comment: `(7, 'Girls\' Generation', 'SNSD', '2007-08-05', 'SM', 5, 9, 'SONE', true),` - incorrect columns amount.

Comment: thank you, i just realised some columns have only 9, not 10

Comment: getting issues here still (37, 'Uni.T', null, '유니티', '2018-05-18', 'Unit Culture', 8, 9, null, false),
(38, 'KHAN', null, '칸', '2018-05-23', 'Maroo', 2, 2, null, false),

(49, 'Purple Kiss', null, '퍼플키스', '2021-03-15', 'RBW', 7, 7, 'PLORY', true),
(50, 'LIGHTSUM', null, '라잇썸', '2021-06-10', 'Cube', 8, 8, 'SUMIT', true),

Comment: i found the issues.. missing a bunch of commas and values haha